# Assembla subversion constantly asks for credentials in the browser when consulting a repository

Tags: svn, assembla

I am totally new to assembla so my question may seem silly but I don't currently have the answer.

I have a subversion repository hosted on assembla. When I try to access it for reading via the browser, an authentication pop-up appears. I don't know how or why it appears.
It turns out that by entering any username and password, I can then access the files.

[image]

How can I make this authentication window disappear? I've already tried to search the settings but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted assembla. It turns out that they made an update inducing the addition of a mandatory authentication popup for each project (even if you don't want it, in this case any login will work but it induces users consulting the repository).
So we made the choice to migrate the project to a GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

Your web browser should give you an option to save/cache your username and password for Basic authentication. If it does not, then I'd suggest that you double-check if password caching is disabled in the browser. I think that it can also makes sense to address your question to Assembla's support.